# Asp.net WebForms Silent Authentication AAD on Teams Tab

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-teams

I'm looking a way to build a Web Forms App C# 4.7 with Azure Active Directory (AAD) Authentication like a SSO Authentication. 
This WebApp was deployed on Azure Web Application.

I'Would like to use this site from : 
Web Browser - all

Teams Tab (adding this to teams as a Tab) -- Working on Web and Desktop App

I'have try 3 option :

1/
Using Azure Web Application Authentication (configuration with our AAD) it's work fine on Web Browser and on Teams Web
But doesn't Work on Teams Desktop App...

2/
Implementation off OWin Auth with AAD V2 OAuth2 on C# code it's work like the 1 option. But doesn't work on Teams Desktop App....

3/
Now I'm looking a way i think this it's good way but i didn't find use on WebForms C# .Net project
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-tab-aad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth is a web-based protocol that relies on redirects between URLs. When your tab is running inside the Teams client, there is no URL to redirect back to, so authentication fails (that's what's happening when you run your tab in the desktop client). You need to have Teams initiate the authentication process for you: you can't do it directly. This method also works in the browser, and the user experience is improved because the login doesn't occur in a separate browser tab, it occurs in a modal popup.

You need to use the tabs SDK method `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate()`. The usage of this is explained in great detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-flow-tab). (The URL you found is a companion article specific to AAD and doesn't have the overview information.)

There's a C# example here: [Microsoft Teams tab authentication sample (C#)](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp).

Comment: Thx Bill, i'm trying to reproduce this example on Web Forms app. But if i build my website authentication with the use off the SDK (microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate()) this always work on web browser ? or i have to implement 2 distinct way to authenticate.

Comment: Hi Bill, i think the Microsoft Teams tab authentication sample C# doesn't have what i'm looking for, in this exemple i have only Bot utility sample. I doesn't find the same sample as a Node https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/tree/master/src/views/tab-auth

Comment: I'have find this but it's on 404 not found : https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-csharp

Comment: @sanpas - that's the wrong URL, the right one is https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp.