# Auto authenticate users in Microsoft teams using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am looking to see how I can integrate authentication to a bot using Azure AD. There is a nifty code Microsoft offered in this [article about authentication with azure bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). What it does is offer a sign in option to users, they log in and authenticate by copy/pasting the 6 magic numbers back to the chat. I used AADv1 example to test it in Teams.

Here is the direct github link to the cs file where the GetTokenDialog is (line 95): [github link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AadV1Bot/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs)

However I am having trouble finding a way that it automatically authenticates the user in Microsoft Teams since we use SSO within corporate network.

The picture in this link,[Microsoft Teams bot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcmFp.png), is from a Who bot that you can download to Teams and talk to it. It basically does the authentication automatically after the user initially clicks "Allow".

Is there a way to replicate this process?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can inform you.

[botframework on teams channel 1:1 Authentication AAD integrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090597/botframework-on-teams-channel-11-authentication-aad-integrated)

At this time it's can't possible to SSO your bot on teams channel but you can compare the tenantId of your AAD.

Note of response (Adrian Solis) : Currently, there's no way to get the user's AAD token automatically-- you have to get the user to go through a login experience (as described in the documentation links you posted above) to get an AAD id or access token.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Pascal! What I am confused is how come the Who bot can do it? It because it's an app service and not a bot?

Comment: I think you're true. The T-Bot Microsoft Corp was deployed on teams as a Bot and as a Tab teams application. 
It's probably use the Microsoft Teams SDK (javascript).
Show thoses link : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-tab-aad
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302873/asp-net-webforms-silent-authentication-aad-on-teams-tab

Comment: @pascal sanchez is correct in that Auth recently added to bot framework is not natively designed to work like this.   There would have to be Some sort of customization involved.